# image is not loaded properly in email when it was sent from odoo application

Tags: url, binary, python-3.7, odoo-13, email-templates

When I sent the email from sales, purchase or invoice module, I could recieve the mail but the image is not loaded, how could I fix the issue

[image: E mail Template]

Comment: Can you check that you are facing this issue in your local environment or in your production environment?

Comment: I am facing this issue in local environment

Comment: For production environment too you can suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Belive me it's because of the **local environment** sometimes it'll cause the issue in odoo, because it is hosted on your local system , I think you can check on the **production server** , It will work as expected as you think.

If it's not solved in the production environment too than we can think about the coding part.

Thanks.